# Can 2 different random variables have the same CDF?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm looking for proof that two different random variables can have the same Cumulative Distribution Function; in other words, I'd like to disprove that a CDF uniquely defines a random variable. (Probably a silly question, but I couldn't find anything usable so far).

Comment: Define "different".  Is a variable that is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$ different from one that is uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$, or over $[0,1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $X$ such that $P(X=0)=P(X=1)=\frac12$ and $Y=1-X$. Then $Y\ne X$ in the sense that $P(Y=X)=0$ but the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ coincide.

For continuous random variables, choose $X$ uniform on $(0,1)$ and $Y=1-X$, or $X$ standard normal and $Y=-X$.

Comment: Could you please explain explicitly what does Y = 1 - X mean in the discrete case? I'm guessing that e.g. for flipping a coin, X assigns 0 for head and 1 for tail, and in this case Y would assign 0 for tail and 1 for head, I'm not sure of the abstraction of the example.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @AndrásSzilveszter $Y=1-X$ and $X\in\{0,1\}$ means that $Y=\begin{cases}1 & : X=0 \\ 0 & : X=1\end{cases}$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $X$ to be a random variable on $\{0,1\}$ with $P(X=1)=P(X=0)=0.5$.

Consider also $Y$ to be a random variable on $\{0,1,2\}$ with $P(Y=1)=P(Y=0)=0.5$ and $P(Y=2)=0$.

Do $X$ and $Y$ have the same cdf?

Comment: But X=Y almost surely and in such case one usually says the random variables coincide.